# Не получается умножить число на строковый тип используя .format

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, строки

Можно ли в выражении вида `'{0}{1}'.format(4, s)` внутри кавычек умножить число `{1}` на строковое значение к примеру `"#"`

Comment: `'{0}{1}'.format(4, "#" * s)`

Comment: а именно внутри кавычек, а не в самом .format(), это можно сделать? или может используя какой-нибудь синтаксис зациклить эти решётки?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> s = 5
>>> x = "#"
>>> f'{a}{x * s}'
'4#####'
>>>
```